# COMO DAR GRANT A UN USUARIO SOBRE UNA TABLA QUE TIENE COLUMNAS DE TIPO ARRAY

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

como puedo dar permisos de select, update, delete insert a un usuario sobre una tabla que tiene un campo de tipo array por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE esquema.tabla
 (
    columna1              VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    columna2             VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    columna3              COL.TYPE_ARRAY,
    columna4              COL.TYPE_ARRAY
  );
```

Estoy tratando de dar este permiso:

```
 GRANT SELECT,DELETE,INSERT, UPDATE ON esquema.tabla TO MyUSER;
```

Me arroja el siguiente error:

```
GRANT SELECT,DELETE,INSERT, UPDATE ON esquema.tabla TO MyUSER
Error at line 1
ORA-01720: grant option does not exist for 'COL.TYPE_ARRAY'
```

Ya trate incluso de dar gran execute sobre COL.TYPE_ARRAY

Comment: ¿Cuál es la definición del tipo de dato denominado "COL.TYPE_ARRAY"?